# What does `def` in scala evaluate to?

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

I wrote this is Scala Repl

```scala
def sum(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
```

This is evaluated as
`sum: (a: Int, b: Int)Int` in Repl. `def` in Scala is lazily evaluated. So, what is the type that Repl displays? Also, how is this eagerly evaluated when `sum(1,2)` is called or how is `(a: Int, b: Int)Int` evaluated to `Int`?

I noticed this when I was playing with `val` in Scala. If I write `val sum = (a: Int, b: Int) = a + b` this is eagerly evaluated into `(Int, Int) => Int = <function2>` which is fine as the `apply` function call is made. But I don't understand what happens in case of `def`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala

Comment: @DmytroMitin yep that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sum: (a: Int, b: Int)Int` displayed by the REPL is a bit of compiler internals leaking to the userland.

`sum` is a method, so there is no actual *value* of type `(a: Int, b: Int)Int`, but the compiler internally associates `sum` with something called *method type* - it's a type that holds method signature - its parameter names and types + result type. This type exists only in the compiler and cannot be directly written in Scala code.

Comment: As a minor caveat: method types are described in the language specification (https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#method-types), they aren't just compiler internals.